# How to use using with iterator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can I declare an iterator in c ++ using the USING command?

```
using myVectorIterator = std::vector<int>::iterator;
```

And this is my for

```
for (myVectorIterator = vector.begin(); myVectorIterator != vector.end(); myVectorIterator++)
```

I have an error in '=' and '!='.

Comment: Is you actual variable called `vector`?

Comment: @doctorlove - Weird, but legal. I suppose that's why the fully qualified `std::vector` is used.

Comment: I know - I just wonder if this code isn't really the code that's going wrong...

Comment: _I have an error in '=' and '!='_  and you think you should keep back **what** error you got?

Comment: Consider using `auto`as in: `auto itr = vector.begin();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myVectorIterator` is a type alias, not an object. You need to declare an actual iterator:

```
for(myVectorIterator itr = ...; itr != ...; ++itr) {
}
```

Or go the easier route, with `auto`:

```
for(auto itr = ...; itr != ...; ++itr) {
}
```

Maybe even the easiest, just use a range for:

```
for(int i : vec) {

}
```

Choose the one that gives you as much information as you need per iteration.

Comment: I would add the possibility of using `auto` in the first for loop.